# URL Redirect from .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

How can I redirect url of format

```
www.example.com/movies/[anything]/[anything]/[string].html
www.example.com/tv/[anything]/[anything]/[string].html
www.example.com/videogame/[anything]/[anything]/[string].html
```

to

```
www.example.com/redirect/movies/[string]
www.example.com/redirect/tv/[string]
www.example.com/redirect/videogame/[string]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @anubhava here is what I ended up with.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^movies/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$  redirect/movies/$3 [L,NC,R]
 RewriteRule ^tv/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$  redirect/tv/$3 [L,NC,R]
 RewriteRule ^videogame/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$  redirect/videogame/$3 [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place this rule in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^.]+/)\.html$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava for your reply, we do not have .htaccess option to place under test. I have just updated the question.

Comment: thanks again @anubhava. I am still having issue as rewrite rule is not redirecting the url.

Comment: Make sure this is your very first rule... and use latest updated rule.